# Should Data Mapper reference Domain Model?

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, dns, datamapper

Hey guys.
I'm reading Martin Fowler's PoEA. Data Mapper pattern is working with Domain objects in this way:

```
class AbstractMapper... 

   protected DomainObject load(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
      Long id = new Long(rs.getLong(1));
      if (loadedMap.containsKey(id)) return (DomainObject) loadedMap.get(id);
      DomainObject result = doLoad(id, rs);
      loadedMap.put(id, result);
      return result;
   }
   abstract protected DomainObject doLoad(Long id, ResultSet rs) throws SQLException;

class PersonMapper...

   protected DomainObject doLoad(Long id, ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
      String lastNameArg = rs.getString(2);
      String firstNameArg = rs.getString(3);
      int numDependentsArg = rs.getInt(4);
      return new Person(id, lastNameArg, firstNameArg, numDependentsArg);
   }
```

It means that Data Mapper that is DAL references Domain. I thought that DAL must not have such references. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any layer, including a presentation layer or a data access layer, can reference the domain model.  However, the domain model should not reference those layers so it can potentially be re-used to support alternative interfaces and persistence strategies.

Comment: Thanks for answer, just one moment. If domain doesn't reference DAL then how it will use it? Maybe it isn't required to reference DAL directly, however it need to have  some interfaces to work with data source.

Comment: The DAL should be concerned with persisting domain objects, not the domain.  So, if one of your domain objects is a Customer entity, in the DAL you might have something like CustomerRepository with methods that load and save Customer entities.  I have seen this logic incorporated into the domain itself too, so I'm not saying this is the one true way to structure a project, but it seems cleaner to me.

Comment: Hmm, As repositories work with domain objects then they have access to domain objects' methods that are domain logic. Of course it is clear that these methods must not be used in repositories, however there is no incapsulation. Maybe it needs to use interfaces in Repositories to encapsulate business logic from DAL?